# Установка одного deploy-token на группу проектов gitlab

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Насколько мне известно "токен развертывания" присваивается один на проект, группе проектов выдать его не возможно, но на самом деле так ли это?
В компании работал некий devOps и каким то образом установил на группу проектов один токен, каким образом он это сделал никак не могу разобраться, т.е. в конфигурации докера на всех проектах из группы один и тот же токен.
Это достаточно удобно, особенно если группа проектов это микросервисы и записываются в один docker-compose.yml и запускаются одним ранером.
Deploy key как я понял из документации не работает с docker или docker-compose.
Подскажите, каким образом можно установить один deploy token на группу проектов?
Спасибо!

Comment: https://you.domain/groups/you_group/-/settings/repository
Другими словами в настройках группы проекта, если у вас есть права, там все идентично, что и в проекте. Если я правильно понял вопрос

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов как же все просто оказывается, при том что я просил человека с правами мейнтейр попробовать добавить deploy token, права на добаление есть только у владельца проекта. Оформите пожалуйста как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для группы проектов можно добавить **Deploy token** точно так же как и для отдельно взятого проекта. Посмотрите хватает ли вам прав.
Настройки находятся по пути group -> settings -> repository

Comment: Действительно проблема была в доступе, странно что в интернете не много информации по этому поводу, спасибо!